# Removing all repeated elements in a linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

Given a sorted linked list, delete all nodes that have duplicate numbers, leaving only distinct numbers from the original list.

Example 1:

```
Input: 1->2->3->3->4->4->5
Output: 1->2->5
```

Example 2:

```
Input: 1->1->1->2->3
Output: 2->3
```

I have tried and succeeded in my code with most cases, the only case I am missing is when the list ends in duplicates and there are non duplicates throughout.

```
class Solution:
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        first = head
        if first is None:
            return []
        second = head.next
        if second is None:
            return first
        first.next = second
        if first.val == first.next.val:
            while first.val == first.next.val:
                if first.next.next is None:
                    return []
                first = first.next
            return self.deleteDuplicates(first.next)
        else:
            first.next = self.deleteDuplicates(first.next)
            return first
```

The error I get for [1,2,3,4,4] is "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'val'".

Comment: why are you doing `return []`, that's the culprit of your errror

Comment: Omg that was the issue thank you so much, I did return [] because in a previous problem that would be the final output so it was fine. I changed the it to just "return" and the code works!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in $O(n)$ time and $O(n)$ space (worst case) by just keeping track of what you've seen so far, assuming your data is hashable.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def mark_duplicates(current_node, seen_so_far):
    next = current_node.next
    seen_so_far[current_node.data] += 1
    if next is None: return seen_so_far
    return mark_duplicates(next, seen_so_far)

def remove_duplicates(current_node, seen):
    next = current_node.next
    prev = current_node.prev
    if seen[current_node.data] > 1:
        if prev is not None: prev.next = next
        if next is not None: next.prev = prev
        # No need to delete current_node, the GC will do it
    if next is not None: remove_duplicates(next, seen)

notes = mark_duplicates(head_of_list, defaultdict(int))
remove_duplicates(head_of_list, notes)
```

A `defaultdict(int)` is just a dictionary that'll return 0 when you try to access a key that doesn't exist. So this counts how many times each value appears, then removes everything that's shown up more than once.

Comment: While I appreciate your help, I am well aware there are other ways of solving this problem, and most are probably more efficient. What I wanted to know is why my way isn't working in the specific cases I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, I just needed to change return [] to simply "return" as [] wasn't being recognized as an empty linked list, but rather just an empty list. Thanks to  Devesh Kumar Singh for recognizing this error, but he didn't post it as an answer so I am posting it on his behalf.

Comment: You don’t need to post an answer for this on my behalf, since this is a typo in your code, unlikely to help future readers looking at your question